# TurboFrame & Stimulus Search form fails to execute search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am going through a software engineering book called Modern Front-End Development for Rails, Second Edition by Noel Rappin. In one section of the book, I am trying to create a search form with turbo and stimulus so that when I type in input, it will automatically submit through javascript and the page that I am on will show the desired search result that I want. I've followed the book and double checked my code but it seems that the search bar is not working for one reason or another.

What makes this feature difficult to troubleshoot is that I do not see any errors in the rails terminal, no output in the browser console tab, no error logging, etc. It simply does not do a thing when I type. Below is the following pieces of code that is supposed to make the search work.

1. app/views/schedules/_search_form.html.erb

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag("search-form") do%>
  <div data-controller="search">
    <%= form_with(
          url: concerts_url,
          method: "get",
          data: {
            "turbo-frame": "search-results",
            "search-target": "form",
            action: "input->search#submit"
          }
        ) do%>
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-4/5">
          <%= text_field_tag(
                "query", "",
                placeholder: "Search concerts",
                type: "search",
                id: "search_query",
                "data-search-target": "input",
                class: "w-full px-3 py-2 
                        border border-gray-400 rounded-lg"
              ) %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= turbo_frame_tag("search-results") %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

2. app/javascript/controllers/search_controller.ts

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import "form-request-submit-polyfill"

export default class SearchController extends Controller {
  static targets = ["form", "input"]
  formTarget: HTMLFormElement

  submit(): void {
    this.formTarget.requestSubmit()
  }
}
```

3. app/javascript/controllers/index.js

```
import { application } from "./application"


import SearchController from "./search_controller.ts"
application.register("search", SearchController)
```

4. app/controllers/concerts_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @query = params[:query]
    @concerts = Concert.all
  end
```

5. app/views/concerts/_search_result.html.erb

```
<article class="my-6 max-w-screen-lg">
  <div>
    <%= concert.start_time.by_example("Jan 2 @3:04PM") %>
    <div class="font-bold text-xl">
      <%= link_to(concert, data: {"turbo-frame": "_top"}) do %>
        <%= highlight(concert.name, /#{query}/i) %>
      <%end %>
      <div class="float-right">
        <% if concert.sold_out? %>
          Sold out
        <% else %>
        <%= pluralize(concert.unsold_ticket_count, "Tickets") %>
          Remaining
        <%end%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= highlight(concert.bands.map(&:name).join(", "), /#{query}/i) %>
  </div>
  <div><%= concert.genre_tags.split(",").to_sentence %></div>
  <div><%= concert.venue.name %></div>
</article>
```

These 5 pieces should work together and should highlight on my page the search term that I want. But like I mentioned before, nothing is being submitted, going to the controller, or updating. It simply doesn't do anything with no errors reported. How can I troubleshoot this feature effectively? If there is something glaring that I am not seeing I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You say nothing on the browser console tab, but what about the network tab? You should see the request happen.

Comment: Hey @Chiperific thanks for pointing that out. I looked at the network tab and its definitely not sending any request at all.Could there be something else i may be missing?

Comment: This makes me think Stimulus is not actually doing it's job. Try adding to Stimulus controller: `connect() { console.log('I got the connection!');}`

Comment: I added that line and it is indeed not doing anything. I wonder if I'm missing some kind of step somewhre.

Comment: All my other stimulus controllers are working correctly though. I wonder if there is a rails command im missing or something.

Comment: `search_controller.ts` is weird to me. I thought it was a typo, but you have it in `index.js` too. Is that the correct extension? I think it should be `.js`

Comment: I'm using typescript for the stimulus controllers hence the `.ts`.

Comment: Not a Javascript expert but all my Stimulus controllers don't show any class name such as here : `export default class SearchController extends Controller {`

Comment: @Maxence if you run `rails g stimulus <controller>` that is the output that is produced in the code.

Comment: Oh my Bad. Thought it was really a syntax issue somewhere as `connect()` don't actually connect DOM elements to JS.. Not too sure now..

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I am able to submit the form with `this.element.submit`, but it breaks out of the turboframe and reloads the page or navigates away. If I submit the form via button it will behave as expected.